# compile error cannot bind 'std::basic_ostream<char>' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'

Tags: c++, compilation

I have a movie class with as method in header & cpp:

movie.h

```
#include "book.h"
#include <vector>

class Book;
class movie
{
public:
    movie(string aTitle, int aYear);
    void fromBook(const Book &b);
    string toString() const;

private:

    std::vector<Book> book;

};
```

movie.cpp

```
#include "movie.h"
#include <sstream>

    movie::movie(string aTitle, int aYear):
    title{aTitle}, year{aYear}
{

}
    void movie::fromBook(const Book &b)
    {
        book.push_back(b);
    }

    std::string movie::toString() const
    {
        stringstream result;
        result << "\nA film adaption from the book: " << std::endl;
        for (auto a : book)
          {
          result << "\t" << a;
          if (a != *(book.end()-1))
            result  << ", ";
          }
        return result.str();
    }
```

For some reason it gives me the error:

```
error: cannot bind 'std::basic_ostream<char>' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
       result << "\t" << a;
              ^
```

Althought I don't really understand why.

When using the same method to print a list of string for example, I don't get this error.

FYI: I removed the code that wasn't relevant. I only kept anything to do with the book thing. (and the original constructor)

Comment: 1) Format your code. 2) Don't wildly mix `std:` and unqualified names -- qualify everything consistently. 3) Show complete code. 4) The code you show doesn't match the error message.

Comment: Where is `return(result << "\t" << a);`? You forgot the most important piece of code.

Comment: It does? There is a random "z" that went in there when pasting the code, ill edit it now

Comment: I editted. I copied the wrong error. I had tried to use a return(); around it to fix it but that didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler cannot find an `operator<<` for `Book`.

The closest match it finds if one from the standard library

```
template<class _CharT, class _TraitsT, class _Ty>
std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _TraitsT>&
  operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _TraitsT>&& _Stream, const _Ty& _Value);
```

where `_Ty` might match `Book`, but your `result` isn't an rvalue and so doesn't match the `_Stream` parameter. Unfortunately, that makes the error message less than clear.

You should see to that you have an `operator<<` for `Book`, and that it is visible in movie.cpp.

Comment: (answering a now deleted comment...) You are trying to insert `a` into the stringstream,  but the compiler doesn't know how to do that - it cannot find the `<<` to use in `<< a`. You either have to create such an operator, or replace `<< a` with `<< a.title << a.author`, or whatever fields a `Book` contains.

Comment: I found the problem, that's why I deleted my comment. Yes indeed! You are  right. If I however do want to be able to just call " << a ", I can overload the << operator in the book class I guess